# Mutability in scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, sicp

I'm working with modifying a list in scheme and was wondering basically how mutability is usually done (or if it's done at all). Here is one example of "adding positions to a chess board".

```
; representing a chess position as (col, row), using 1-based indexing
(define (make-position col row) (cons col (list row)))

(define empty-board '())
(define (add-new-position existing-positions col row)
  (append existing-positions (list (make-position col row))))
```

And using them:

```
(define B1 empty-board)
(set! B1 (add-new-position B1 1 2))
(set! B1 (add-new-position B1 2 4))
(display "B1=") (display B1) (newline)
; B1=((1 2) (2 4))

(define B2 empty-board)
(add-new-position B2 1 2)
(add-new-position B2 2 4)
(display "B2=") (display B2) (newline)
; B2=()
```

Is the above usually how mutability is handled (using `set!`)? Is that fine to do, or usually discouraged in scheme or other functional programming languages? And if it's discouraged, how would someone, for example, debug in the middle of "building a list" ?

Comment: It depends on the application. Sometimes mutating is useful, sometimes it isn't.

Comment: You're not modifying the list. `append` makes a copy of all its arguments except the last one, and that one is freshly-made with `list`. You're just modifying the global variable.

Comment: In a case like this you could very easily do `(define B1 (add-new-position (add-new-position empty-board ...) ...))`.